# Adding a text clock to PowerPoint using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to add a clock to a PowerPoint slide, and it has to show the current time, which means it has to update once every second. This is my current macro:

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition

    MsgBox "Macro still working!"

    'With ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes("Date Placeholder 8")
    '    Do
    '        Sleep 1000
    '        .TextFrame.TextRange.InsertDateTime ppDateTimehmmssAMPM
    '        DoEvents
    '    Loop
    'End With
End Sub
```

This shows a MsgBox with the text "Macro still working!" as expected. However, if I remove the apostrophes, thus (supposedly) allowing the update code to run, nothing happens, and I don't see a MsgBox. Can anyone help?

I've tried using the AutoDateTime add-in, and it works, except there are animations that need to run on my slide and AutoDateTime keeps interrupting those animations. I've also tried TM Timer and it has the same problem.

Comment: To get your code to run as is, you'll need to define the Sleep sub as described here: http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00466_Put_your_macro_to_Sleep.htm

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the problem I had, but now I have another issue: I can't advance the animations in my presentation at all. I suspect it has something to do with the infinite loop I'm running, which unfortunately needs to run to keep the clock updated. Is there a way I can have this macro run in the background?

Comment: Just a hunch, but try putting the loop and the update code in a form. Have the code start as soon as the form loads but don't actually show the form.

Comment: I experimented with this yesterday. A couple of things: 1) You probably want to handle events as Microsoft recommends, here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/use-events-with-the-application-object

Comment: 2. 2) For some reason, the macro code does not change the target shape when you change slides, even if you get the target slide from the value returned in the event. This is where you might start troubleshooting